# Angularjs and Highcharts directive in Nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

In my application i create a directive that draw Highcharts chart .

```
  app.directive('chart', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
        config :"=",
        chartObj: "=?"
    },
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.chartConfiguration = {};
        /*scope.$parent.$watch('conf',function(value){
            console.log("aaa");
        });*/
        scope.$watch('config',function(value){
            console.log("1111111111111");
            console.log(scope.config);
            if(value==null)
                return;
            var b = angular.toJson(scope.config);
            /*if(($('.main-div').find('pre').html())!=null)
                $('.main-div pre').remove();*/
            $('.main-div pre').html("<pre class='.configuration'>"+angular.toJson(scope.config)+"</pre>");
            scope.chartConfiguration.chart = scope.config.options.chart;
            scope.chartConfiguration.series = scope.config.series;
            scope.chartConfiguration.chart.renderTo = iElement[0];
            scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart(scope.chartConfiguration);
        });

    }
};
}])
```

in my directive i use `$watch` to watch properties of object. but it's only watch on property that is not nested. forexample if i want to change `$scope.conf.options.chart.type` the watch doesn't understand . for this problem i create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DETiDF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$watch` with the third argument, an `objectEquality` flag, set to true like this:

```
scope.$watch('config',function(value){
  // your code
}, true); // set objectEquality flag to true here
```

Also see: [$scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: when i use third argument `true` it make's infinite loop and browser crash.i think this object has it own reference to itself.

Comment: Highcharts might be change the configufation inplace. Could you please try passing a copy of `scope.config` to Highcharts instead?